# Cannot run Pumba on Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I want to try `Pumba` [Yaml file](https://gist.github.com/lordofthejars/3a342bc8ac7e253ccec35b7ff69f56a1) on my `Openshift` Cluster.My pod is giving `CrashLoopBackOff`.
After checking the logs I found the error to be this

`container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"pumba\": executable file not found in $PATH"`.

If anyone evere faced any error like this?.

Comment: Change `command: ["pumba"]` so that you give the full pathname to the `pumba` executable in the image, because right now it doesn't look like it is in the standard `PATH` as message says.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton what should I change it to?.

Comment: Look at what its `Dockerfile` uses. https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile#L93 Note that you may find the image will not even run, because it is designed to run as the `root` user, which OpenShift prohibits you from doing by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image doesn’t contain any shell as an entry-point to execute `pumba` command.

So, what you need to do is to change yaml as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: pumba
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: pumba
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: orangesys/alpine-pumba:0.2.4
        name: pumba
        args:
          - pumba
          - --debug
          - --random
          - --interval
          - "30s"
          - kill
          - --signal
          - "SIGKILL"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: dockersocket
            mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
          name: dockersocket
```

Works as expected

```
AME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pumba-qdqx6   1/1     Running   0          38s
```

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: @GauravSingh any luck?

Comment: No, My pods for Pumba are falling into `crashLoopBackOff`

Comment: I made changes according to what you said.

Comment: Yes @A_Suh I do not  even know if even it's possible to use it or not

Comment: @GauravSingh sorry, there was a wrong image. I've just update my yaml above and tested it - works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the updated YAML :), it worked but I think I'll not be able to achieve what I'm trying to achieve because I'm getting this error .
***time="2019-07-30T07:18:42Z" level=error msg="Get http://unix.sock/v1.15/containers/json?all=0&size=0: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?"***

Comment: Or maybe I'm missing something!. I don't know :/

Comment: @RajatSingh seems like docker service is not running, but I'd recommend to start another topic if you need help with this, it's slightly off topic with original post. Also if my answer helped you to run pumba on K8s pls accept it )

Comment: you can also upvote my question so that it can help others :)